# Malformed calls from JS React Native Async Storage

Tags: react-native, asynchronous, async-await

I came across this error today in an attempt to use AsyncStorage and was unable to resolve it.

My attempt:

```
import { APP_NAME } from 'react-native-dotenv';

export const createOrUpdate = async(key, content) =>{
    try{
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('@' + APP_NAME + ":" + new String(key), new String(content));
    }catch(error){
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

The error: Error: Exception in HostFunction: Malformed calls from JS: field sizes are different.

does anyone have any idea how to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is recommended that you use [react-native-easy-app](https://github.com/chende008/react-native-easy-app/blob/master/README.en-US.md), through which you can access AsyncStorage synchronously, and can also store and retrieve objects, strings or Boolean data

```
  import { XStorage } from 'react-native-easy-app';
  import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
  // or import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

   export const RNStorage = {
       token: undefined, 
       isShow: undefined, 
       userInfo: undefined
   };

  const initCallback = () => {

       // From now on, you can write or read the variables in RNStorage synchronously

       // equal to [console.log(await AsyncStorage.getItem('isShow'))]
       console.log(RNStorage.isShow); 

       // equal to [ await AsyncStorage.setItem('token',TOKEN1343DN23IDD3PJ2DBF3==') ]
       RNStorage.token = 'TOKEN1343DN23IDD3PJ2DBF3=='; 

       // equal to [ await AsyncStorage.setItem('userInfo',JSON.stringify({ name:'rufeng', age:30})) ]
       RNStorage.userInfo = {name: 'rufeng', age: 30}; 
  };

  XStorage.initStorage(RNStorage, AsyncStorage, initCallback);
```

Comment: I couldn't quite understand how this package works. I didn't understand where RNStorage comes from, so I left my storage utility this way: https://gist.github.com/ThallyssonKlein/cb28e689ec556f0491adb61e33f88091. Then after that I call the function that the storage should be used this constant and change the token value. Should the utility in question save the value at the right time? However, when I run the APP again and import this constant into any other class, the token value is undefined.

Comment: Sorry, the example I gave is not complete, and it has been corrected. RNStorage is actually an ordinary object object that you define yourself. For specific use, you can refer to the example project on my github :https://github.com/chende008/react-native-easy-app/blob/master/README.en-US.md.